# Cannot download email, error code 80048830

Tags: 8.1, email

I have a Nokia Lumia 520 with Windows Phone 8.1, and I can no longer download email messages. When I try, I get an error with the code 80048830.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What email service are you using? Outlook.com? Gmail? Something else? Did it work previously? Have you changed anything recently that might cause this? Does the error say anything besides that code?